# jmter performance testing-concurrent users

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

i want to do performance testing with 100 concurrent users hitting the service.

can you please guide what is the configuration we need to do in jmeter .i need to use http request also for sending json file.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to have 100 threads configured in thread group.
2. You can use    httpRequest sampler to post the json content

Answer (score 0):

1. For general JMeter configuration: check out [Building a Web Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html)
2. If you're sending JSON most likely you'll need to add a [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) configured to send `Content-Type` header with the value of `application/json`
3. Use [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer) in order to send all 100 requests at exactly the same time